# Visual studio 12 and validation error

Tags: asp.net

I have used asp.net validation in visual studio 2012.But following error is showing
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your app setting of web.config. I was having similar issue resolved via this.

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="WebForms" />
</appSettings>
```

For more information see following link.

http://forums.asp.net/t/1819175.aspx?Help+with+WebForms+UnobtrusiveValidationMode+requires+a+ScriptResourceMapping+for+jquery+Please+add+a+ScriptResourceMapping+named+jquery+case+sensitive+error

and also there is a work around this issue.

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/735928/in-asp-net-web-application-visual-basic-the-requiredfieldvalidator-doest-work